# How midi match to sampler?

Tags: c#

I'm planning to create a project to play midi files to a custom-made sampler that was recorded in .wav format. Current I able to play the midi through GM, but I don't know how to "match" midi to the sampler.

I'm currently looking at C# Synth and NAaudio but facing difficulty as their documentation is not thorough.

Your assistance is very much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "matching" MIDI to the sampler? Do you want to connect to specific MIDI device? Is the custom sampler you mention hardware or software?